# DB decision on choosing way to create a monitoring servers project

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on project called "Monitoring servers" where i need to start from scratch. When i plan for DB tables, i'm getting confused on how to and where to start DB tables.

1. Register.php (db_register where user_id is primary key)
2. login.php (db_login where user_id is primary key)
3. servers.php (db_servers) = Here Every user can add multiple servers and should be visible depending on logged in user. 
   For example, User1 logged in and added his own server (say google.com) user2 added yahoo.com

So should i need to create seperate db for every user ?
 
or 
 
It is enough to create all common tables with differentiating unique user_id ?

Can you guys give me suggestions on how to start ? ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is... this just sounds like a basic relational database application?

Comment: I'm just confused on "How to create tables which can linkup other related tables". Here, Every user should be able to add multiple servers, and every server can have multiple services. There is also possible to add same servers by different users with different services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at something called Foreign Keys (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key).

These are used to link relational tables together.

For example, a users table will have a primary key of user_id.

The servers table will have a primary key of server_id, but a foreign key of user_id. This is used to relate that server to a user.

If you wanted to get all servers that a certain user owns (Say that user has a user_id of 5), you would do a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `db_servers` WHERE `user_id` = 5
```

Comment: No problem - if you need further detail, then don't hesitate to ask :-).